# SQL obter apenas os resultados que dêm match

Tags: mysql, sql

Boa tarde **SO**,

Estou preso aqui numa query que é a segunte:

```
SELECT a.name, 
       am.reference_id, 
       m.imdb_id 
  FROM movies AS m, 
       actors AS a, 
       actors_map AS am 
 WHERE am.reference_id = "tt0397892"
```

Tenho a tabela `movies`, `actors` e `actors_map`.

Tabela `movies` ex:

| id | Nome do filme | imdbid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bolt | tt0397892 |
| 2 | Hitman | tt0000001 |
| 3 | Matrix | tt0000002 |

Tabela `actors` ex:

| id | Nome do ator |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jason Statham |
| 2 | John travolta |
| 3 | Dwayne Johnson |

Tabela `actors_map` ex:

| id | actors_id | reference_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | tt0397892 |
| 2 | 1 | tt0000001 |
| 3 | 1 | tt0000002 |

O output que estou a ter de momento mesmo com o **WHERE** a "pedir" para mostrar apenas os atores no `actor_map` que tenho o `actor_map = tt0397892`: é-me mostrado todos os atores da coluna `actors`..

O output que queria era este:

| id | actors_id | reference_id | Nome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | tt0397892 | John Travolta |

O que estou a fazer mal na minha `query`?

Agradeço desde já toda a ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com base na estrutura de tabelas que você informou o que faltou fazer foi um JOIN entre as tabelas. Movies e actors_map são unidas pelos campos movies.imdbid x actors_map.reference_id e os actors são unidos ao actors_map pelo actors.id x actors_id.actors_id.

Sua consulta ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT a.name, am.reference_id, m.imdb_id 
FROM movies AS m 
INNER JOIN actors_map AS am ON m.imdbid = am.reference_id
INNER JOIN actors as a ON a.id = am.actors_id
WHERE am.reference_id = "tt0397892"
```

Comment: só uma nota, as aspas `"` devem ser aspas simples `'` :)

Comment: Obrigado! Não só pela resolução mas também pela explicação (que é o que mais aprecio). JOIN entre as tabelas é algo que ainda não estou muito familiarizado :(